# Error installing dbt-core through pip install

Tags: python, installation, dbt

During the installation, pip install dbt-core throws the following error.

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

It seems werkzeug 2.2.2 requires  MarkupSafe>=2.1.1, but the only available is markupsafe 2.0.1, which is incompatible.

How would I fix that dependency?

Best wishes,
I

```
Collecting future
Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
 |████████████████████████████████| 829 kB 48.4 MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: minimal-snowplow-tracker, logbook, parsedatetime, future
Building wheel for minimal-snowplow-tracker (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/iuri/Projects/Dbt/dbt-core/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/minimal-snowplow-tracker/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/minimal-snowplow-tracker/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-qfen18y8
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/minimal-snowplow-tracker/
Complete output (6 lines):
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for minimal-snowplow-tracker
Running setup.py clean for minimal-snowplow-tracker
Building wheel for logbook (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/iuri/Projects/Dbt/dbt-core/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/logbook/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip- 
install-mbj4aicc/logbook/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-9v3wdqqr
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/logbook/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

 error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for logbook
 Running setup.py clean for logbook
 Building wheel for parsedatetime (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/iuri/Projects/Dbt/dbt-core/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/parsedatetime/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/parsedatetime/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-rmissiks
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/parsedatetime/
 Complete output (6 lines):
 usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

 error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for parsedatetime
 Running setup.py clean for parsedatetime
 Building wheel for future (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/iuri/Projects/Dbt/dbt-core/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/future/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/future/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-0f8w6wij
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mbj4aicc/future/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

 error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
 ----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for future
 Running setup.py clean for future
 Failed to build minimal-snowplow-tracker logbook parsedatetime future
 ERROR: werkzeug 2.2.2 has requirement MarkupSafe>=2.1.1, but you'll have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

...

Answer (score 1):

This is a current bug ([link to issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4745)) and the workaround is to downgrade the markupsafe library to 2.0.1

`pip install --force-reinstall MarkupSafe==2.0.1`